# Selection sort with doubly linked list

Tags: c++, sorting

I have been working tirelessly on this but can't seem to figure out the problem. I have tried numerous changes and Debugger as well and it says `Exception thrown GetNext() returns nullptr`. I can't seem to figure out what I am missing here. This is what debugger is throwing at me

```
The thread 0x1b14 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: read access violation.
**this** was nullptr.
```

This is the function I wrote for **selection sort** on doubly linked list.

```
template <class T>
void InsertionSort(ds::dn::Node<T>* root)
{
    ds::dn::Node<T> *temp=root->GetNext(), *temp1, *changer;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        temp1=root;
        while(temp1!=NULL || temp1!=temp)
        {
            if (temp!=NULL && temp1!=NULL && temp->GetData() < temp1->GetData())
            {
                if(temp1->GetPrev()==NULL)
                {
                    if(temp->GetNext()!=NULL)
                    {
                        changer = temp;
                        temp=temp->GetNext();
                        changer->GetPrev()->SetNext(changer->GetNext());
                        changer->GetNext()->SetPrev(changer->GetPrev());
                        temp1->SetPrev(changer);
                        changer->SetNext(temp1);
                        changer->SetPrev(NULL);
                        temp1=temp;
                    }
                    else if(temp->GetNext()==NULL)
                    {
                        temp->GetPrev()->SetNext(NULL);
                        temp->SetPrev(NULL);
                        temp1->SetPrev(temp);
                        temp->SetNext(temp1);
                        temp1=temp;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(temp->GetNext()!=NULL)
                    {
                        changer=temp;
                        temp=temp->GetNext();
                        changer->GetPrev()->SetNext(changer->GetNext());
                        changer->GetNext()->SetPrev(changer->GetPrev());
                        changer->SetPrev(temp1->GetPrev());
                        temp1->SetPrev(changer);
                        changer->SetNext(temp1);
                        changer->GetPrev()->SetNext(changer);
                        temp1=temp;
                    }
                    else if(temp->GetNext()==NULL)
                    {
                        temp->GetPrev()->SetNext(NULL);
                        temp->SetPrev(NULL);
                        temp1->SetPrev(temp);
                        temp->SetNext(temp1);
                        temp1=temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                temp1 = temp1->GetNext();
            }
        }
        temp=temp->GetNext();
    }
}
```

Here is the **node header**.

```
{
    template <class T>
    class Node
    {
    private:
        T data;
        Node<T>* next;
        Node<T>* prev;

        Node(const Node<T>& obj);
        Node& operator=(const Node<T>& rhs);
    public:
        Node() : data(T()), prev(NULL), next(NULL) {}

        Node(const T& data) : data(data), prev(NULL), next(NULL) {}

        Node(const T& data,Node<T>* prev,Node<T>* next) : data(data), prev(prev), next(next) {}

        ~Node() {}

        T& GetData() {return data;}

        const T& GetData() const {return data;}

        Node<T>* GetPrev() {return prev;}

        const Node<T>* GetPrev() const {return prev;}

        Node<T>* GetNext() {return next;}

        const Node<T>* GetNext() const {return next;}

        void SetData(const T& value) {data = value;}

        void SetPrev(Node<T>* link) {prev = link;}

        void SetNext(Node<T>* link) {next = link;}
     }
}
```

Comment: I am not expecting a full code review. Just want to hammer out the main problem.

Comment: The debugger isn't some magic tool that tells you exactly what your bug is and how to fix it. It might tell you *what* went wrong, but it's your job to figure out *why* it went wrong. The error indicated that you tried to dereference a null pointer, so step backwards and use the debugger to figure out what caused the null pointer dereference.

Comment: @BessieTheCow This is what I have been doing and got stuck on.

Comment: How did you get stuck? Think about what your code is supposed to do at each and every step. Then as you step through the code look for when the behavior of the code differs from what you expect. Make sure you inspect the value of variables.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Thanks for the push and encouragement. I have fixed it and its working now. Should I post the working one as my answer?

Comment: If you want, I don't think it really matters.